# Pascal/Delphi dynamic array as argument

Tags: arrays, delphi, arguments, pascal, dynamic-arrays

I'd like to do something like this:

```
procedure show(a : Array of Integer);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i in a do
    writeln(i);
end;
begin
  show((1, 2));
  show((3, 2, 5));
end.
```

but [this is](http://tpcg.io/WQIXf0gP) the closest I got

```
Program arrayParameter(output);
type
  TMyArray = Array[0..2] of Integer;
var
  arr : TMyArray = (1, 2, 3);
procedure show(a : TMyArray);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i in a do
    writeln(i);
end;
begin
  show(arr);
end.
```

So do I have to declare a different array for each time I want to call the function? Please provide a working example.

Comment: Arrays always imply `[]` - don't mix that up with initializing a variable with `()`, which is unbound to the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do

```
procedure show(a: array of Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i in a do
    Writeln(i);
end;
```

then you may write

```
show([1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

This kind of array parameter is called an [open array parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters). If a function has an open array parameter, you can give it both dynamic and static arrays, in addition to these "literal arrays". So, given our `show` procedure, we may also do

```
var
  DynArr: TArray<Integer>; // = array of Integer
  StaticArr: array[0..2] of Integer;

begin
  show(DynArr);
  show(StaticArr);
end;
```

---

Just for comparison: If you instead do

```
procedure show(a: TArray<Integer>);
```

or has a

```
type
  TDynIntArray = array of Integer;
```

and do

```
procedure show(a: TDynIntArray);
```

then `show` will only accept such dynamic arrays.